# Restrict access to single artifact

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

Is there a way how to restrict access to single artifacts in Artifactory repository?

***Example situtation:***

We have 3 artifacts that are distributed via Artifactory. Artifact A is required by artifact B and C. There are developers who have account and are allowed to download only artifact B (or C).

We don't want them to be able to download C (or B), but we cannot place these artifacts outside this repo, because in that case, we would have 3 repositories (and the number would grow up with more artifacts really fast). Also, developers would have to register 2 repositories to download artifact B.

To sum up again, is there a way to specify permissions in the way that developers (or whoever else) is able to download only certain artifacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a permission target and in the include pattern add an include path of the specific artifact.

You can create one permission target for the B artifact and a different permission target for the C artifact.

Comment: That's great, didn't know about that. It solves my problem.